# Convert JSON number to stars

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Any help would be appreciate. I need to create a slider based on JSON datas from the moviedb API. I created the slider showing the title, the picture and the description within a for loop but the last thing I need to achieve is to get the movie rating but instead of the number I need to show stars (half or full filled according to the datas provided).

I'm stuck and tried different things but it doesn't work. I know it's quite simple but I'm stuck.

Many thanks for any help. Do not hesitate if you need something else because it's my first post on stackoverflow.

Here is the fiddle of my work :

https://jsfiddle.net/y2hbzej8/7/

Here is my JS code to get datas :

**JS :**

```
var urlmoviedb = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=e082a5c50ed38ae74299db1d0eb822fe';

$(function() {
$.getJSON(urlmoviedb, function (data) {
console.log(data); 
for (var x = 0; x < data.results.length; x++) {
    var title = data.results[x].original_title; 
    var descr = data.results[x].overview; 
    var note = data.results[x].vote_average; 
    var noteround = Math.round(2 * note) / 2; 
    var str = "/jj8qgyrfQ12ZLZSY1PEbA3FRkfY.jpg";
    var imageurl = str.replace("/jj8qgyrfQ12ZLZSY1PEbA3FRkfY.jpg", "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280");
    var image = imageurl + data.results[x].backdrop_path;
    $('#image').append('<li>' + '<h2 class="h2-like mt-4">' + title + '</h2>' + '<p class="note">' + noteround + '</p>' + "<img class='img-fluid mb-4' src='" + image + "'>" + '<p class="descr">' + descr + '</p>' + '</li>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please look through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the article on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Hint: While a Fiddle is not a problem, please also include the most important code within the question itself.

Comment: Post your code in the question and not a hack to get around the filter.

Comment: Of course @epascarello, sorry.

Comment: Not really familiar to this API, vote_average goes from 0 to 10? If so, you need to come up or find a way in order to convert that field value into number of stars, are you taking in consideration halfstars or only full/empty stars?

Comment: @ggderas it seems like the range is from 0 to 10 but I'm not sure. In the array the max note is 8.4. I did a Math.round so that I can only get an integer but with a half sometimes so yep it would be great to have full/halfstars.

Comment: @Player_One I would divide the vote_average values by 2, since values go from 0 to 10, this would give me values based from 0 to 5. Then you can either round them considering only integers (no half stars) or round them considerating decimals (half stars). Trying to come up with the rate based on five stars is the real problem I believe, grab some star icon from icons8.com or google them.

Comment: @ggderas Yes I can do that but then I don't know the steps to convert the values into stars...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the vote_average field of each row by two since values go from 0 to 10. This will give you five stars based values.

I edited your example, I added font-awesome CSS library that will give you lots and lots of icons you can play with. [Check them out](https://fontawesome.com/)

Here's the [edited example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2hbzej8/18/)

```
var urlmoviedb = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=e082a5c50ed38ae74299db1d0eb822fe';

$(function() {
$.getJSON(urlmoviedb, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (var x = 0; x < data.results.length; x++) {
    var title = data.results[x].original_title;
    var descr = data.results[x].overview;
    var note = data.results[x].vote_average;
    var noteround = Math.round(2 * note) / 2;
    var str = "/jj8qgyrfQ12ZLZSY1PEbA3FRkfY.jpg";
    var imageurl = str.replace("/jj8qgyrfQ12ZLZSY1PEbA3FRkfY.jpg", "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280");
    var image = imageurl + data.results[x].backdrop_path;

    //Translate vote average field into number of stars by dividing them by two since vote_average goes from 0 to 10
    var numberOfStars = Math.round(note/2);
    var stars = '';

    for(var index = 0; index < numberOfStars; index++)
        stars += '<span class="fa fa-star"/>';

    $('#image').append('<li>' + '<h2 class="h2-like mt-4">' + title + '</h2>' + "<img class='img-fluid mb-4' src='" + image + "'>" + '<p class="descr">' + descr + '</p>' + stars + '</li>');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Wonderful ! Works like a charm and easy. It was so simple...Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Accept the answer as your solution so StackOverlow can know this is the best solution for you

Comment: Done. Thank you !